# how to use .change to disable select

Tags: javascript, html

i really need a quick answer for this.
how can i disable a select option once value has changed?

it must be available on firstload, then after the user tries to select it first time, it is the disabled for further change. so the user can choose a value only once.

HERE is my code which is dynamic?

```
                                    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" >
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
                                            <TD>
                                                    <select name="ItemNo[]" id="select" value="ItemNo" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
                                                          <?php           
                                                          $sql2="select * from jewelry_system.item where NumStored !='0' order by ItemName asc";
                                                          $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                                                          while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                                                          ?>
                                                          <option value="<?php echo $row2['ItemNo']?>"> <?php echo $row2['ItemName'];?>     Php:<?php echo $row2['SalePrice'];?> </option>
                                                          <?php } ?>
                                                    </select>       
                                            </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                    </TABLE >
```

what do i put in the javascript?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want if it's in your `onChange` event

```
this.disabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks. can i ask more?
can you suggest a query about this code also.
just above the table on the code above is this code: 

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />          <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

they add another row of select option on the table, i cant figure out how ,such that the next row of select option, the option previously selected is not included in the next select option values? thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Without extending the loadXMLDoc method or adding another method to disable the field the cleanest method would probably be to append    this.disabled = true to your select.onchange declaration

```
<select name="ItemNo[]" id="select" value="ItemNo" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value);this.disabled = true;">
```

Comment: thanks. can i ask more?
can you suggest a query about this code also.
just above the table on the code above is this code: 

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />          <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

they add another row of select option on the table, i cant figure out how ,such that the next row of select option, the option previously selected is not included in the next select option values? thanks btw